# Pass shell parameters to awk regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
file="path/to/file"
/usr/bin/awk '/chapter:/ {f=0} /chapter: 25/ {f=1} f' $file
```

how can I use a variable's value instead of `25` ?

something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="path/to/file"
num=25
/usr/bin/awk '/chapter:/ {f=0} /chapter: <num>/ {f=1} f' $file
```

p.s.

1. `/usr/bin/awk -v n="$num" '/chapter:/ {f=0} /chapter: n/ {f=1} f' $file`is not working
2. I cannot use any other tool for that, because `awk` is the fastest one for what I want o do

any ideas?

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on right track here but for the 2nd part of building the regex. You can use:

```
awk -v n="$num" '/chapter:/{f=0} $0 ~ "chapter: " n {f=1} f' file
```

You need to build the regex using variable `n` and use `~` operator for regex matching.